# How to load json data using AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to load JSON data into HTML file.
Problem is, it does not load json data and when I add error event then it gives me error alert for error object. Please guide me how I could resolve this issue. even, I could not find any specific alert to identiy the error. how to resolve this ? Is there any way to get actual error while working with jquery/ajax ?
Below is my html file which has jquery call to json data with html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>


<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn382").click(function () {
            /* set no cache */
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

            $.getJSON("car-sale.json", function (data) {
                var html = [];
                alert('result');

            });
        });
    });
</script>

   </head>
 <body>
   <input type="submit" id="btn382" />
  </body>
   </html>
```

JSON file is as follow:

```
[{
"Manufacturer": "Toyota",
"Sold": 1200,
"Month": "2012-11"
}, {
"Manufacturer": "Ford",
"Sold": 1100,
"Month": "2012-11"
}, {
"Manufacturer": "BMW",
"Sold": 900,
"Month": "2012-11"
}, {
"Manufacturer": "Benz",
"Sold": 600,
"Month": "2012-11"
}, {
"Manufacturer": "GMC",
"Sold": 500,
"Month": "2012-11"
}, {
"Manufacturer": "HUMMER",
"Sold": 120,
"Month": "2012-11"
}]
```

Comment: If you add a fail handler, it has three arguments telling you what the error is, so why not use that instead of just alerting `error` ?

Comment: what is the signature and what is the property of error object to get actual error ?

Comment: Just do `$.getJSON(url, callback etc...).fail(function() {console.log(arguments)});`

Comment: is car-sale.json located in same directory as this html file?

Comment: yES, It is in same directory. I added .error event then, it gives me error as `Not Found`.. file is I same directory though..

Comment: did  u check the mails ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the page header you should define this

```
<script src="car-sale.json"></script>
```

i check this with a firefox and its working fine check this with firefox

```
$.getJSON('car-sale.json', function (data) {

                 $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                console.log(val.Manufacturer );
                });

            });
```

Comment: copied same but not worked. json file is also located at same level where index file is existed.

Comment: added script file into header.. no luck.

Comment: `Not Found` error.. looks like unable to locate json file and giving me this error. when i add into variable then it works fine.

Comment: i created this as working do u need it ? give me your email ID i will send it

Comment: can u make this as answer ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58578/discussion-between-user3711357-and-littledragon).